# Generated client code not returns value

Tags: jax-ws, wsimport

I have generated java classes using the JAX-WS wsimport tool.  I am trying to call webservice using this generated stub, but the client code hangs and gives no response for a long time.

However, when I try to call the same webservice request using SOAPUI, its returns the proper response successfully. For all of the methods I am getting successful responses, I only get this issue for one request.

(Due to privacy concerns I am not able to source code.)

Comment: It's hard to help you with only that information ...

Comment: Try posting a simplified version of your code; remove any information that might compromise you and we can probably still help you. But we don't have crystal balls.